# CSS issue in Nested Master Pages

Tags: css, master-pages

I am having a problem about CSS for my pages. 
In my solution I have the following elements:

1. Master Page (Outer)

   - css fileOuter1
   - css fileOuter2
   - css fileOuter3
2. Master Page (Inner)

   - css fileInner1
   - css fileInner2
3. Webpages - Inheriting from "Master Page Inner"

   - Page Contents

I don't want the files "css fileInner1" and "css fileInner2" to affect the "Master Page (Outer)". 
They should only be affect the "Master Page (Inner)" and "Webpages".

But currently, they are affecting the "Master page (Outer)"
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Which kind of styles you want to be unaffected on base master layout? Ideally CSS styles in child master page doesn't affect parent one if they have different classes/selectors.

Comment: I am referring some CSS in outer Master. I just want those to be applied to it. I don't want the CSS from Inner master to affect the outer master. Currently the CSS inheritance works both ways. Not sure how to fix this ? See this:   https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29001031/CSS-issue-in-Nested-Master-Pages.html